# Can I create an accepted eventrelation in an apex test class

Tags: unit-test

I am creating test event relation data using the following code, which fails:

```
   list<eventrelation> ers = new list<eventrelation>();
    for(contact cur : [select id from contact where lastname !='Starter']){
     ers.add(new eventrelation(eventid=party.id,relationid=cur.id,status='Accepted'));  
    }
    insert ers;

    integer attendeecount = [select count() from acceptedeventrelation];
    system.assertequals(ers.size(),attendeecount);
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Your system asserts will fail if you have not used @seealldata annotation. Paste ur full test class please

Comment: How does it fail? Is it your assert that is failing? Did you create a Contact with the required last name in your testing data.

Comment: Yes, it is the assert that is failing. The contact was created in earlier code.